# Нужна помощь , писатели на python! [маккрос]

Tags: python, click

*Хочу написать вопрос на питоне, но не выходит по той или иной причине. Я пока что только новичок на питоне, и в связи с этим знаний мне не хватает. Суть заключается в том, что при зажатии кнопки мышки, ее клики ( вместо одного зажимания - должны идти быстрые клики) . К слову , как быстро кликать, я давно понял, и применил, а вот как это встроить при нажатии и чтобы деактивировалось после отжимания клавиши - мне не понятно. Буду благодарен за помощь!*

P.S. Только что понял, что программа считает mouse.click() - за условие while, и из-за этого цикл - бесконечный.

```
import mouse
import win32api


def auto():
    mouse.click()
    sleep(2)
    print('a')

 
while True:
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01):
        auto()
```

Comment: может ошибусь, у вас GetAsyncKeyState чтото возвращает, но неважно что- делаем авто. посмотрите его значения и поправьте условие. # while True по условию есть бесконечный цикл, вне зависимости от кликов.

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать:

```py
import mouse
import win32api
from time import sleep

def auto():
    mouse.click()
    sleep(2)
    print('a')

while win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) < 0:
    auto()
```